# Icon packs on stock Huawei Launcher

Tags: root-access, huawei, app-icons

Is there any way to use icon packs on the stock launcher in the same way they can be used on third-party launchers? I have a Huawei P8; it is rooted so I'm guessing there is a way but my searches have come up empty so far.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? What were you trying to accomplish, I'm sure the icons are store in the theme file (.hwt). You can decompress the file by simply renaming it to a .zip and extract the png of the icons